# Splitting CSV file by row

Tags: python, csv

Someone, please review this code for me. I am kind of confused with the path in the code. By the way, the code is for splitting CSV file based on a number of rows, got it on GitHub and by using it have been trying to split a CSV file but the code is too confusing for me.

You may also follow the link for the code [click to see the code](https://gist.github.com/traviswaelbro/fefc37b1ad36196e6b92cbb8cba8baa6)

Assuming that, the name of the csv to be splitted is `Dominant.csv`,
source_filepath is `C:\\Users\James\\Desktop\\Work`,
dest_path is `C:\\Users\James\\Desktop\\Work\\Processed`,
`result_filename_prefix` is `split`,

My confusion is, 
Is `target_filename` in the code means my csv file `Dominant.csv`? and what exactly is this `target_filepath`?

Could someone please reformat the code for me as per the given path and file names? Would be really thankful

```
import csv
import os
import sys


if len(sys.argv) != 5:
    raise Exception('Wrong number of arguments!')


SOURCE_FILEPATH = sys.argv[1]
DEST_PATH = sys.argv[2]
FILENAME_PREFIX = sys.argv[3]
ROW_LIMIT = int(sys.argv[4])


def split_csv(source_filepath, dest_path, result_filename_prefix, row_limit):
    """
    Split a source CSV into multiple CSVs of equal numbers of records,
    except the last file.
    The initial file's header row will be included as a header row in each split
    file.
    Split files follow a zero-index sequential naming convention like so:
        `{result_filename_prefix}_0.csv`
    :param source_filepath {str}:
        File name (including full path) for the file to be split.
    :param dest_path {str}:
        Full path to the directory where the split files should be saved.
    :param result_filename_prefix {str}:
        File name to be used for the generated files.
        Example: If `my_split_file` is provided as the prefix, then a resulting
                 file might be named: `my_split_file_0.csv'
    :param row_limit {int}:
        Number of rows per file (header row is excluded from the row count).
    :return {NoneType}:
    """
    if row_limit <= 0:
        raise Exception('row_limit must be > 0')

    with open(source_filepath, 'r') as source:
        reader = csv.reader(source)
        headers = next(reader)

        file_number = 0
        records_exist = True

        while records_exist:

            i = 0
            target_filename = f'{result_filename_prefix}_{file_number}.csv'
            target_filepath = os.path.join(dest_path, target_filename)

            with open(target_filepath, 'w') as target:
                writer = csv.writer(target)

                while i < row_limit:
                    if i == 0:
                        writer.writerow(headers)

                    try:
                        writer.writerow(next(reader))
                        i += 1
                    except:
                        records_exist = False
                        break

            if i == 0:
                # we only wrote the header, so delete that file
                os.remove(target_filepath)

            file_number += 1


split_csv(SOURCE_FILEPATH, DEST_PATH, FILENAME_PREFIX, ROW_LIMIT)
```

Comment: Please post the code here instead of posting the link!

Comment: Dominant.csv is your source file and target_filename.csv is name for the resulting file that will be split into bits. target_filepath is the location you want the resulting file to be stored.

Comment: [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

target_filename is the name you want the output file to have.
target_filepath is the path to the output file including its name.
In the split_csv function call:
SOURCE_PATH is the path to the source file
DEST_PATH is the path to the folder you want the output file in
FILENAME_PREFIX is what you want the output file name(s) to start with
ROW_LIMIT is the maximum number of rows per file you want written to the output file.